# How to animate a fixed div with jQuery without page scrollbar resetting to top

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, css-position

first post here, so be kind ;-)

I have a fixed 'menu' div in the body of a page, mostly hidden 'offscreen', in the right-hand margin, with its initial top and right set in CSS to show only a 'handle'.

The div scrolls OK with page content and I've introduced jQuery's animate function to slide this div out of the margin and back, when needed - as the handle is clicked. It's a simple script, simplified as...

```
var x = document.getElementById('menu');
if (x.style.right == '0px') {

        $j("#menu").animate({
            right:'-148px'
        });
    } else {

        $j("#menu").animate({
            right:'0px'
        });
    }
```

The issue is that whenever this menu div animation is triggered to 'open' or 'close', the page resets to top (its scrollbar position resets). I've tried adding code to trap and reset the scrollbar position but that introduces a 'flicker' effect on the page.

Any clues on how to fire the animation without affecting the page's scroll position?

Best,

Keith..

Comment: Can you reproduce this using http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return false` at the end of click event or set href of link to `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip Panjkaj. The function is being called by a link onClick and href='#' rather than a jQuery click function on the div. Deleting the href sorted it nicely! Best, Keith..

Comment: Sorry, slight typo in my comment - I meant that redefining the href to the suggested javascript void reference solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Just for your knowledge, if you have onClick then you can add return false like this, `onClick="javascript line1;javascript line2;return false;"`, then you can leave `href="#"`. If you have some function like `onClick="showMenu()"` then add `return false` as last line in showMenu function body.

Comment: Thanks again, Pankaj - useful variants and snippets for the reference library! :-)